# Trying to only do math functions on edittexts users have entered information in on android

Tags: android, android-edittext, average

I have a 10-field average lap calculator. However, in testing, someone said they normally only run X laps in practice, vs. 10 (let's say 7).

I think I could use an if statement, but there'd be at least 10 of them and a bunch of clumsy code, and I'm not sure on arrays/switch statements exactly. I think all of those might be possible, but my low level of experience has yet to fully comprehend these useful tools.

CURRENT CODE:

```
double tenLapAvgVar = ((lap1Var + lap2Var + lap3Var + lap4Var + lap5Var + lap6Var + lap7Var + lap8Var + lap9Var + lap10Var) / 10);
```

So essentially, if someone leaves a field or fields blank, I want to calculate the average based on the populated fields, not 10 (if they leave 3 fields blank, calculate based on 7, for instance). Any help you guys could provide would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You must be taking those values as `String` and parsing them into `Double` before using them,right?

Comment: Correct... taking EditText values as entered by the user in 10 other fields and parsing them from strings to doubles so they can be calculated. App works flawlessly as is, just needs the flexibility added in.

Comment: Both the answer given are good. You can try to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an `ArrayList<EditText>` object and a method which iterates over it and adds up the values. Something like:

```
    public double getLapAverage()
    {
    int noOfCompletedLaps = 0;

    double lapAve = 0;
    double lapsTotal = 0;    

    for(EditText text : textBoxes)
    {
       if(text.getText().toString().length() > 0)
       {
          //psuedo code, and assuming text is numerical
          lapsTotal += Double.parse(text.getText().toString());
          noOfCompletedLaps++;
       }
    }

    if( noOfCompletedLaps > 0)
    {
       lapAve = lapsTotal / noOfCompletedLaps;
    }

 return lapAve;
 }
```

Comment: So let me make sure I understand what this is doing so I can adapt it properly to my code....

First, we're declaring this is a new method.
Second, inside the ArrayList, we're declaring the integer for which will be the number of laps (starting at 0 of course).

Continue next comment...
Then, we declare the variable for average lap time and then a variable for total lap combined times.
After that, I get a little confused. The Edittext sets a variable for the for statement called "text". What/where does "textboxes" come into play? Is that the total number of text boxes that will be the maximum?

Comment: INside the for statement, we execute an if statement that essentially adds up the number of times that a field is greater than zero or != null, For each one, it adds one to the count. Then, if the count is greater than 0, it averages up appropriately and divides by count. Ultimately, it returns the lap average. Then to put this into the app, I use a line such as "setText.getLapAverage()" correct?

Comment: textBoxes is an ArrayList of your EditText objects. The for loop checks each one for an entry before adding it to the total and incrementing the number of laps. Finally, the total time is divided by the number of laps in order to get the average.

Comment: @TonyStevens remember to accept answers when they have answered your questions. Not saying you need to accept mine in particular, just that accepting answers here on SO make people more likely to answer your questions in future. Cheers!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to put one into practice yet, Barry. Been a crazy weekend with my "day job" at the racetrack, but don't worry, one will be accepted. :)

Comment: Now I've run into an issue of referencing the variables inside the array further down in my code when I click the button. I'm sure it's something stupid, but it acts like the variables need redefined within the other sub-classes, even when I try to make this class "above" them and the other logic "within" it. Suggestions? Otherwise it looks like it works fine the best I can tell.

Comment: Hmm... Not sure. You maybe need to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be better if you used an array instead of 10 different variables.
Then you can use a for statement and initialize them to 0, afterwords let the user fill the array and count how many are not zero.
Finally sum up all the array and divide by the count you previously calculated.